# Get webkitRequestFullScreen -50%

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to get an image to zoom to the real size or 50% of the screen.

i manage to get it working with fullscreen API

```
<img class="zoomE" src="{{ x }}" width="120" height="90" />

<script>
window.onload = () => {
  // (A) GET ALL IMAGES
  let all = document.getElementsByClassName("zoomE");

  // (B) CLICK TO GO FULLSCREEN
  if (all.length>0) { for (let i of all) {
    i.onclick = () => {
      // (B1) EXIT FULLSCREEN
      if (document.fullscreenElement != null || document.webkitFullscreenElement != null) {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) { document.exitFullscreen(); }
        else { document.webkitCancelFullScreen(); }
      }

      // (B2) ENTER FULLSCREEN
      else {
        if (i.requestFullscreen) { i.requestFullscreen(); }
        else { i.webkitRequestFullScreen(); }
      }
    };
  }}
};
</script>
```

My question is, how can i instead of seeting fullscreen set real size or (fullscreen - 50%)?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own overlay system. You could use [the Dialog element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) for baked-in event handling or roll your own like this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.zoomE').forEach((i) => {
        i.onclick = () => {
            zoomEHandle(i)          // display at image natural size
            // zoomEHandle(i, 50)   // display at 50% device width
            // zoomEHandle(i, 100)  // display at full device width
        }
    })
}
function zoomEHandle(imgElement, imgWidth) {
    const imgOverlay = document.createElement('div')
    imgOverlay.id = 'zoomEOverlay'
    imgOverlay.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; height: 100vh; width: 100vw; backdrop-filter: blur(10px); display: grid; place-content: center; z-index: 99;')
    const imgOverlayImg = document.createElement('img')
    imgOverlayImg.src = imgElement.src
    if (imgWidth) {
        imgOverlayImg.style.width = `${imgWidth}vw`
    }
    imgOverlayImg.style.maxWidth = '100vw'
    imgOverlayImg.onclick = () => {
        document.getElementById('zoomEOverlay').remove()
    }
    imgOverlay.appendChild(imgOverlayImg)
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(imgOverlay)
}
```

```html
<img class="zoomE" src="https://source.unsplash.com/pkWRI5q3Jj8" width="216" height="144">
<img class="zoomE" src="https://source.unsplash.com/YGjRs4YUPwA" width="216" height="144">
<img class="zoomE" src="https://source.unsplash.com/0JO4PV-yCVs" width="216" height="324">
```

In order to support both of your requests you'll see the `imgWidth` parameter which should either be left out (to render the image at it's natural size) or be a number up to 100 representing the percentage of the browser's width to scale to (for example 50 from your request).

This code has no error checking or additional handlers like hitting the Escape key or clicking anywhere on the screen but those would be easy enough to add.

There is also the issue of overflow such as the example portrait image I've included. You could adapt the `zoomEHandle` function to receive a generic `imgSize` and then read the `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` of `imgElement`. From there calculate against `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` and add an event listener for the `window` "resize" event.